# Connecting to an open port with bash

Tags: shell, scripting

Is there a possible way to connect to any open port with bash ? i.e without calling any external command.  :)
I wanted to connect to an open port with bash without using nc or telnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the shell; `bash`, for instance, uses I/O redirection to attach to arbitrary TCP and UDP sockets. From the man page:

```
Bash handles several filenames specially when they are used in redirections, as
described in the following table:

    [...]

    /dev/tcp/host/port
        If host is a valid hostname or Internet address, and port is
        an integer port number or service name, bash attempts to open a
        TCP connection to  the corresponding socket.
    /dev/udp/host/port
        If host is a valid hostname or Internet address, and port is
        an integer port number or service name, bash attempts to open a
        UDP connection to the corresponding socket.
```

For example, to get the current time:

```
cat < /dev/tcp/time-a.nist.gov/13
```

Note that it *must* be a redirection; `cat /dev/tcp/time-a.nist.gov/13` would only work if your file system implemented some sort of sockets-on-demand.

A very basic HTTP client:

```
$ exec 3<>/dev/tcp/www.example.com/80
$ echo "GET /" >&3
$ cat <&3
```